# how to install docker compose 2.2.3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker

I could install docker compose 1.18.1 with the tutorial of
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-16-04

To use datalore enterprise version, docker compose 2.2.3 is required, could you give me a hand?

I want to install docker compose 2.2.3 under ubuntu16.04, but 1.18.1 was installed with the docker github repository.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 will be removing binary of existing docker-compose

So most of the installation tutorial will ultimately point to a GitHub repo to you.

In fact, using Curl we technically download the binary and write it to a particular directory.

Here's the link to v2.2.3 release

```
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.2.3
```

Depending upon your os-architecture. you will do like (an example)

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64" \
 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Hope this helps, Thanks.